# Changing a maxHeap Sort to a minHeap Sort

Tags: java, algorithm, heap

I am struggling to work out how to change a maxHeap to a minHeap. I currently have a maxHeap algorithm working but I would like to know how to change it. This is the maxHeap I have used:

```
public static int [][] fixheap(int heap[][], int n, int i){
    int j=2*i;
    int weight = heap[i][0];

    while (j<=n){
        if((j<n) && heap[j][0] < heap[j+1][0])
            j++;
        if(weight >= heap[j][0]) break;
        else 
        heap[j/2][0] = heap[j][0]; 

        j=j*2;
    }

    heap[j/2][0]= data;

    return heap;
}

public static void makeheap(int heap[][], int n){

    for (int i=n/2; i>=0; i--){
        fixheap(heap, n ,i);
    }   
}
```

I have tried reversing certain signs that seem relevant however, I have not found the minHeap. Any help would be great, thanks.

Comment: The code you've posted doesn't look correct and doesn't compile.  What is data?

Comment: About your implementation... First, I don't quite understand why this heap is using a 2D array.  Maybe its a unique constraint of your system. Second, where is the data variable declared or populated? Seems like this implementation needs quite a bit of work to even provide a MaxHeap.

Comment: The 2d array is a system constraint, the values that are returned are a max heap and n is the number of elements within the array.

Comment: #homework tag?  Searching for Java MinHeap renders several sufficient implementations.

Answer (score 1):

The only difference between a min and max heap is the comparator.  If you have a functioning max-heap structure, you should only have to flip the comparator.

Check out [Introduction to Algorithms](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0262033844) on Amazon.  The max-heap structure is described in great detail and is available in the preview or "Look Inside" feature.

Comment: To which comparators are you referring as switching the < > doesnt return a min heap

Comment: @HopelessProgrammer, the point is you don't need a minheap. A minheap is just a maxheap where the smallest item is considered to be the biggest, by flipping `>` and `<`.